# binary variable depending on a continuous variable (mixed integer programming in cplex)

Tags: constraints, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to formulate a constraint for a MIP problem that involves binary variable v and continuous variable i, such as:

if i = 0, v = 0, and
if i > 0, v = 1

I haven't been able to think of a solution to this and I'm not sure if there is a solution. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can also model this using the 'traditional' Big-M formulation which is documented in many places on the internet and in many textbooks.

Usually this is done in a pair of constraints like this:

```
i <= M * v
```

This forces i to be zero if v is zero, and also if i is non-zero then v must be 1 which covers most of your requirement, but still allows i = 0 and v = 1. In many cases the objective is trying to minimise some expression including v and that may be sufficient to encourage v=0 when i=0. But don't fall into the silly error of using a really big value for M as that will adversely affect your linear relaxations and possibly overal performance.

Then you might also need to add a further constraint to force v to zero if i is zero such as:

```
v <= i
```

which would have the effect of directly forcing v to zero if i is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works!

Answer (score 1):

you can rely on logical constraints.
In OPL you can write

```
dvar boolean v;
dvar float+ i;

subject to
{
  v==!(i==0);
}
```

And you can do the same with [all CPLEX APIs](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-part2-python-java-c-cc04558e49b5)